# Need help combining multiple row data from same field, into multiple columns with alias

Tags: alias

I have this table (see below) with rows from same "id" but different "codes" Capital/Expense as shown below.
Need to be able to generate an output that sums the "value" for Capital Codes and Expense Codes in two separate columns. I tried using Where and Alias but running into problems.
My data view table name: budgetcell_view
My data file is as shown below:

| projectid | code | coodename | fieldtypename | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 01-00-000 | capital | cost1 | 325000 |
| 6 | 02-00-000 | expense | cost1 | 250000 |
| 7 | 01-00-000 | capital | cost1 | 200000 |
| 7 | 02-00-000 | expense | cost1 | 125000 |
| 8 | 01-00-000 | capital | cost1 | 400000 |
| 8 | 02-00-000 | expense | cost1 | 210000 |
| 9 | 01-00-000 | capital | cost1 | 550000 |
| 9 | 02-00-000 | expense | cost1 | 330000 |

my desired output is below.... any help will be appreciated:

| projectid | capital_value | expense_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 325000 | 250000 |
| 7 | 200000 | 125000 |
| 8 | 400000 | 210000 |
| 9 | 550000 | 330000 |

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle link which contains the whole table and the DB type you use? Something like this, but changed to your data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d13026a5af63adda96772b2a77fa5db3. Thank you!

Comment: using Oracle 11g DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, you can simply create such a query using a case when construct:

```
SELECT projectid, 
SUM(CASE WHEN code = '01-00-000' THEN value ELSE 0 END) capital_value,
SUM(CASE WHEN code != '01-00-000' THEN value ELSE 0 END) expense_value
FROM table1
GROUP BY projectid ORDER BY projectid;
```

Please see the working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffb48a088579977af2a009003c1c9814)
Please note that you maybe need to extend this query or modify it if there are more difficult options (not only capital or expense), that's why I asked you to provide the entire table data.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. It worked! One more the request... My data table includes an additional data point that I need to add to the WHEN statement. i don't know how. Basically, I need to add "fieldtypename" as an additional filter in the WHEN query.

Comment: Thank you for giving feedback. Please mark the answer as accepted. If you need further conditions, just add them. As example: SELECT projectid, SUM(CASE WHEN code = '01-00-000' AND fieldtypename = 'HelloWorld' THEN value ELSE 0 END) capital_value... And have a nice weekend.

Comment: Thank you so much. All worked as expected. I am new to SQL so this was very helpful.